# C# Making an function(button) that can read an array number

Tags: c#, arrays, button, textbox

I need some help as im confused.
I have to make a button that can read an index of an array I have made.
But my question is how?

My form looks like this http://gyazo.com/9f9ef719532c16e5ac437f1539efbe78
I have to type a number between 7 - 1006 in the search for bar. And then i click "Find" and it should find the number in the "Indhold" and write out the index number in the index box on the right. So yeah im kinda confused what to do now.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        int[] minArray = new int[1000];
        int indPeger = 0;//peger på index i array

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void vScrolIndex_Scroll(object sender, ScrollEventArgs e)
        {
            indPeger = vScrolIndex.Value;
            tbIndex.Text = indPeger.ToString();
            tbIndhold.Text = minArray[indPeger].ToString();
        }

        private void btLinFyld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < minArray.Length; i++)
            {
                minArray[i] = i + 7;
            }
        }

        private void tbIndex_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void tbIndhold_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Code in paste bin is not acceptable on stackoverflow, please add the actual code to the question or this question is way to broad.

Comment: you need to read up on how to use `IndexOf` that's one place to start.. there are so many examples to do this..and actually it's not that difficult..but it's obvious that you have shown / displayed `ZERO` effort on your part

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish with this method `private void btLinFyld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` some advice make your methods match what it is you're trying to do to make it more readable

Comment: Actually i have tried, but when i started the form it stopped working so i might have done something wrong, yes i can just write it to display myArray -7? then it will show the Index number?

Comment: doesn't look like anything actually worked looking at this .. can you get the code back to where you had it working..???

Comment: private void btLinFyld_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) is to display the Index +7 :)

Comment: Read the text from your search box then use it for an input for your array in `btFind_Click`

Comment: I tried to do something like this  

private void btFind_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int aNumber = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);

            int[] minArray;
            minArray = new int[aNumber];
        }

Answer (score 1):

Here's one solution that returns the FIRST instance of the number.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var numbers = new[] { 1, 1, 5, 1, 1};

        var result = Array.IndexOf(numbers, 5);

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

See it woorking here:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/yXoCiX

Comment: +1 Cool. Didn't know **dotnetfiddle.net** exists. =)

Comment: You will print the array out in Console right?

Comment: @Viper I only ran across it a few months back.  Still a little crud but still totally awesome to have for this sort of thing.

Comment: @MeGustaSKINKE This example does, but *ONLY* the first found, it'll return `-1` if it's not found.

Comment: @BanksySan I need help with making an Search bar. I write 555 in the text box and click on Find, and then it will print out the Index inside the Index on the right. I have some problems with that :(

Comment: You can put that value wherever, so `txtMyTextBox.Text = result` should work.  You need to think what you will do if there are zero, or many, instances of the integer you are searching for.

Comment: @Viper Did you know you can have runnable code (JavaScript only) in  questions and responses now?

Comment: @BanksySan Yeah the easy solution is textBox1.Text = indPeger.ToString(); But then i wont be using the find button

Comment: @MeGustaSKINKE It sounds like I need to explain more to you than I can do with some comments here.  Are you asking how do you read and write to text boxes and how do you respond to a click event?

Comment: @BanksySan Yes sir, I'm trying to write a number between 7-1006 into the search bar. Example I write 600 in the search bar and click "Find" then it have to print out 593 in the Index box. Minimum i can write is 7 and maximum i can write is 1006, the minumum Index can show is 0 and the maximum is 999. But yes i need help with write to text boxes etc.

Comment: @MeGustaSKINKE Have a read through this tutorial:  [Create a Picture Viewer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492135.aspx) it seems to take you quite gentle through the basics.  If you have specific questions after that then I'll be happy to help with it.

Comment: @BanksySan I'm afraid that you don't understand me :/

Comment: @MeGustaSKINKE I think I must be.  You write to a text box as above, read from it in the reverse `var myText = txtBox.Text` and you can double-click on the `click` event in the properties box to wire up that event.